# Electron Webview get response

Tags: node.js, webview, electron

I am very new to electron so I may be going about this all wrong.

We have a few web apps internally that are all working and I wanted to practice by building one of them into electron.

What I need to do is load our SSO login page within the app and then listen for a cookie/session to be created after authentication has been successful.

I am using a webview like so:

```
<div style="width:100%; height:100%">
    <span class="loading loader" id="loading" name="loading"></span>
    <webview class="ssologin" src="https://example.com/resources/ldap.php" autosize="on" style="min-width:755px; min-height:640px"></webview>
</div>
```

This loads the login page for ldap/sso. After I login, it would normally take you to the web application you were going to before you were re-routed to SSO do to not having a valid session.

I am trying to figure out how I can listen for a cookie/session so that I know that they have authenticated and we get a response back.

Essentially, I need this valid session in order to make future API calls in the app to endpoints so I want to try and use this existing authentication implementation without having to include other modules and mess with all that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what is that `autosize` attribute ?!?!

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you didn't know: Electron does not currently recommend to use `<webview>`:

> We currently recommend to not use the webview tag and to consider alternatives, like iframe, Electron's BrowserView, or an architecture that avoids embedded content altogether.

Cf https://electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag#warning

You probably need to set a partition on your `<webview>`:

```
<webview src="https://github.com" partition="persist:github"></webview>
<webview src="https://electronjs.org" partition="electron"></webview>
```

> Sets the session used by the page. If partition starts with persist:, the page will use a persistent session available to all pages in the app with the same partition. if there is no persist: prefix, the page will use an in-memory session. By assigning the same partition, multiple pages can share the same session. If the partition is unset then default session of the app will be used.

Cf https://electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag#partition

With that you can (from the main process) access the cookie of the session:

```
const {session} = require('electron');
const sess = session.fromPartition('persist:foobar');
const cookies = sess.cookies;
```

Then you can listen for `changed` events on that cookie object:

> Emitted when a cookie is changed because it was added, edited, removed, or expired.

```
cookies.on('change', () => {
  // do something when your SSO cookie is set
});
```

Cf https://electronjs.org/docs/api/cookies#event-changed

Comment: i always get the error `cannot read property fromPartition of undefined` :/

Comment: [any idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59816741/capture-webview-requests-and-responses) how to capture the requests/responses of a `webview`?